# How to change ordering of stacked columns in mobile using css

Tags: css

I have a css question in regards to ordering columns in mobile. Currently my website has 4 columns and in mobile view they are stacked on top of each other. The columns either have a class of text-column or a class of image column.

Below is an image of how it looks currently in desktop and mobile and as you can see I want to change the order in mobile only.

[image: co]

My question is how to change the order to achieve my desired mobile outcome using css? I am assuming I will need to add extra classes to the columns and then use that to help with ordering. I know I will need to add the @media to the css to ensure it only happens in mobile and tablet.

Comment: Can you share your code on codepen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can target individual items and change where they appear in the **visual order** with the `order` property.

Ref:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items

**DEMO:**

```css
.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .col div:nth-child(1) {
    order: 1;
  }
  .col div:nth-child(2) {
    order: 2;
  }
  .col div:nth-child(3) {
    order: 4;
  }
  .col div:nth-child(4) {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="text">.text column</div>
  <div class="img">.image column</div>
  <div class="text">.image column</div>
  <div class="img">.text column</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply include the top two divs in a new `div`, like suppose `<div id='first-row'>`, and similarly another `<div id='second-row>` for the bottom two divs. So the `first-row` and `second-row` divs will always remain separate, one after another. And inside the divs you can place the `.text-column` and `image-column` divs.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I'd use flexbox here, then it's easy to change the layout for mobile.

Please read these articles:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items

Flexbox is great and I recommend learning it.